# Django form populated by content of an object is not refreshing

Tags: django

I am new to Django and probably made a mistake.

I created forms.py containing:

```
from django import forms
class CustForm(forms.Form):
    OPTIONS = ([(account.id, account) for account in Account.objects.filter(active=True)])
    CustId = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=OPTIONS)
```

In views.py:

```
from .forms import CustForm

def listcust(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            customer = form.cleaned_data.get('CustId')

            applist = Appliance.objects.filter(cslic=customer)
            customer = Account.objects.get(id=customer)
            return render(request, 'addapp/listapp.html', {'customer' : customer, 'applist' : applist })
    else:
        form = CustForm()
    return render(request, 'addapp/listcust.html', {'form':form })
```

This works but if I change the "active" attribute of an Account, the content of the drop down menu does not change until I restart/reload Apache.

Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you try refreshing the page with your browser cache disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because it does the query at runtime.

One method would be to use a ModelChoiceField

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Another method would be to return the OPTIONS with a method or lambda.

Another method would be to do the operation in the **init** of the class.

Comment: Thank you. Using ModelChoiceField worked and is actually cleaner.

I might have misunderstood the suggestion of returning OPTIONS via a method but my attempts failed.